# How to insert localized meta-tags from provided language files?

Tags: xul

I wonder if there exists another solution, to insert localized extension meta-tags automatically **without adding them manually to install.rdf**, for example by using a language variable (see example below):

example: *myextension/chrome/locale/ru-RU/install.dtd*

> mylang.description=example description

*my install.rdf:*

```
<em:localized>
  <Description>
    <em:locale>ru-RU</em:locale>
    <em:description>&mylang.description;</em:description> //<-- inpossible?
  </Description>
</em:localized>
```

or by a method, that **automatically overwrites the standard install.rdf's `<description>-tag`** with the user's language (from a file provided in myextension/chrome/locale/[LANG]/*  ?

---

**background:**

so far, we've translated the `<description>-tag` (and sometimes the `<name>-tag` too) for more than 20 languages - i'm just looking for a way, to manage this tangle inside my install.rdf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide localized descriptions via a localized preference pointing to a `.properties` file in your locale directory, see [Localizing before Gecko 1.9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Localizing_extension_descriptions#Localizing_before_Gecko_1.9) (this approach is still supported despite the article title). However, this approach has the disadvantage that the descriptions are only available if the extension is enabled - if the user disables your extension only the description from `install.rdf` will show up. Which is why I prefer using build scripts that will generate localization info in `install.rdf` from files in the locale directory.